# What's the mechanical 'whoosh, whoosh' sound in this video?

Tags: boeing-737, cockpit, noise

Sound in question comes right after the warning sound at 22:57.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Or associated with an entertainment simulator feature then a real airplane or aviation

Comment: That's a real sound. I just couldn't find a video with an actual cockpit footage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the sound of the trim wheel rotating on the center console of the Boeing 737.

The trim wheel controls elevator trim. It can either be moved automatically by the autopilot, or manually by the pilot. The pilot can push the trim button on the yoke with their thumb (left for the captain, right for the copilot).

[image]

<sub>This is a photo of a B737 classic series, but this feature is unchanged on the NG series.</sub>

In this specific instance, it sounds like there were two small manual push on the trim button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I learned something new today thanks to you.

Comment: That is supposed to be the trim wheels? Somebody needs to work on the sound effects on that sim.